# How can I automatically copy HTML from an existing website to my new website?

Tags: html, google-sites

I am trying to add an element to my website at the moment and don't know how I can code it. I want to have a section of a different website on the one I am making. I can copy across the HTML code for the other website to my one, but this does not update on mine as the existing one does. I am working on google sites so it's wanting HTML and the best way I can see to do this is by coding it to automatically copy across the HTML from the other website; however, I don't know how to do this. I have tried using an iframe, and a couple of other things but I haven't got anything to work so far. Hopefully, that makes sense, I'm not strong enough at coding to know where to go from here so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sites is a bit weird and because it already has code in it and the code you copy and paste might not turn out the way you wanted, so if you want to make a website, you should use a code editor like Visual Studio Code, Brackets, Atom, Notepad++, etc. Also, I'm pretty sure there is a section on Google Sites that lets you enter a URL and then it adds the thing in.